# Autocorrelation and cross-correlation of chaotic time series

Tags: random, chaos-theory

I want to check if a time series is (a) random or not (b) independent. For these I am using the autocorrelation (AC). Autocorrelation
refers to the correlation of a time series with its own past and future values.

If random variables are independent then there should be no correlation between them. The reverse is not true.

I am learning what techniques are there to show if a chaotic nonlinear dynamical system from which the time series is obtained can be a good generator of PRBS. I am following the tests given in paper : A New Pseudo-Random Number Generator Based on Two Chaotic Maps

Question  : In general, for nonlinear time series, Lyapunov exponents tells us if the system is chaotic or not. But, for my case, I have to transform the values to +1/-1. In this case, would finding Lyapunov exponents be valid?

Comment: Is there any reason why you mention the second time series and the cross-correlation in your question?

Comment: I want to check randomness and independence for the bitstream that is generated from the chaotic real valued numbers. From your answer, since the Lyapunov exponents test is not valid for bitstream, I did the autocorrelation test. In many papers, the bitstream /symbolic dynamics are considered to be outcomes of $i.i.d$ Bernoulli process. Also, chaos based cryptography (the paper which I mentioned) using chaos mention tests to check for randomness and correlation. The Authors say that the samples are not correlated. I am confused as to why the bitstream are considered as Bernoulli process.

Comment: There are too many questions here. Please ask only one question at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general, for nonlinear time series, Lyapunov exponents tells us if the system is chaotic or not. But, for my case, I have to transform the values to +1/-1. In this case, would finding Lyapunov exponents be valid?

Estimating the Lyapunov exponents from a time series inherently requires to look at trajectories that have a small distance at some point (to see how they diverge from each other). If your time series is symbolised as you describe, the minimum distance two trajectories can have is 2, which is close to the diameter of the attractor. Hence, unless you do a high-dimensional embedding, you cannot even reasonably calculate the Lyapunov exponent.

> I cannot interpret the graph, what the spike indicates and if the graph provides information about randomness and independence. I am not very familiar with chaotic time series, but based on the equation of the map, is chaotic time series independent or correlated?

I am not familiar with Matlab, but apparently it rescaled your plot in a weird manner. The auto- and cross-correlation should not obtain absolute values larger than one. Considering this and the symmetry of the autocorrelation plot, I would presume that the peak in the autocorrelation is actually located at 0, where there is no delay and you are looking at the correlation of the data with itself, which is always 1.

It looks as if there is a non-vanishing auto-correlation outside this, and your time series is hence correlated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Some things are not clear, could you please elaborate? (Confusion 1): In general, if the cross-correlation = 1, then the two sequences are uncorrelated. What should I expect for cross-correlation between two bitstreams obtained from chaotic system and auto correlation between samples of a bit stream?

Comment: (Confusion 2):Then, for checking randomness of bitstream and chaos real valued numbers what tests should I perform?

Comment: *In general, if the cross-correlation = 1, then the two sequences are uncorrelated.* – No. The cross-correlation is 0 if the sequences are uncorrelated. — *What should I expect for cross-correlation between two bitstreams obtained from chaotic system […]?* – if your stream is long enough and the systems do not interact with each other: 0 — *[…] and auto correlation between samples of a bit stream?* – 1 for no delay; significantly non-zero for some short delays; practically zero for long delays.

Comment: *Then, for checking randomness of bitstream and chaos real valued numbers what tests should I perform?* – I am not sure that I understand you, but: It is impossible to distinguish a symbol time series generated by a chaotic process from one generated by a Markov process with memory, e.g. [this paper of mine](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.011030) features a symbol time series generated from a chaotic system that can be fully described by a second-order Markov process. Every sufficiently complex deterministicity is indistinguishable from stochasticity.

Comment: Thank you for the first and second reply to the 2 confusions. I will certainly go through the paper. Lastly, could you please confirm that for chaotic time series and its bitstream, I should have the autocorrelation to be 1 for no delays. If so, then what does this information  say about independence property ? Is a chaotic time series and its bit stream independent or correlated?

Comment: The autocorrelation of **every** time series is 1 for no delay by definition. The cross-correlation (for no delay) between a chaotic time series and its symbolisation should be high but not 1, indicating that you lost some information through the symbolisation.